# Error "call to a member function on a non-object" with PHP function

Tags: php, api, function

I am new to php functions, so bear with me. Here is my code:

```
<?php

require('AuthnetCIM.class.php');

    $cim = new AuthnetCIM('26JspTq3A', '6S97jCdwS56P3rGs',AuthnetCIM::USE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER);

function add_profile()
{

    // Create unique fake variables
    $email_address = 'user' . time() . '@domain.com';
    $description   = 'Monthly Membership No. ' . md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $customer_id   = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 16, 16);

    // Create the profile
    $cim->setParameter('email', $email_address);
    $cim->setParameter('description', $description);
    $cim->setParameter('merchantCustomerId', $customer_id);
    $cim->createCustomerProfile();

    // Get the profile ID returned from the request
    if ($cim->isSuccessful())
    {
        $profile_id = $cim->getProfileID();
    }
    // Print the results of the request
    echo '<strong>createCustomerProfileRequest Response Summary:</strong> ' .$cim->getResponseSummary() . '';
    echo '<strong>Profile ID:</strong> ' . $profile_id . '';
}

add_profile()
?>
```

My problem starts with this line: $cim->setParameter('email', $email_address);

I get the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function setParameter() on a non-object

I know this code works when its not in a function, this is just the next step. I am sure there is something simple I am missing with this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has scoping. You need to import the function with `global` (**not recommended**) or pass as parameter. The `$cim` variable is not automatically available in the function.

```
function add_profile($cim) {
    // ...
}
add_profile($cim);
```

*or (**not recommended**)*:

```
function add_profile() {
    global $cim;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I went with the add_profile($cim) option since everyone said don't user global.

Answer (score 0):

In your `add_profile` function, you either need to:

1. Pass the `$cim` object in as an argument; or,
2. Make `$cim` a global to the function by using `global $cim;` inside the function at the top.

Otherwise, right now, it's out-of-scope.